# Reference/pointer to array of enums not getting the right valu

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, enums, casting

I have an array of enums:

```
typedef enum {
    Item0,
    Item1,
    Item2
} ITEMS_TYPE;

ITEMS_TYPE MyItemsArray[] = {
    Item0,
    Item1,
    Item2
};

bool findIndexOfItemInArray(int32_t valueToFind, int32_t* arrayToScan, int32_t arrayLastIndex, int32_t* indexOfTheSearchedValue)
{
    int32_t index;
    int32_t value;

    for(index = 0; index < arrayLastIndex; index++)
    {
        //value = static_cast<int32_t>(arrayToScan[index]); //this when C++
        value = (int32_t)(arrayToScan[index]); //this when C
        if(value == valueToFind)
        {
            *indexOfTheSearchedValue = index;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    int32_t valueToFind = 0;
    int32_t itemIndex;

    findIndexOfItemInArray((int32_t)valueToFind, (int32_t*)MyItemsArray, Item2, &itemIndex));
}
```

My problem is that

```
arrayToScan[index];
```

inside the `findIndexOfItemInArray()` function is never the integer value of the given item but some weird, long number.

It all works when I compile it in C, but in C++ it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the actual code, a [mcve]. In the enum you did post there is no `Item2`

Comment: Yes, I stop the code. When it didn't work first time I added the
value = static_cast<int32_t>(arrayToScan[index]);
to easily read the value under the exact index. But it's not the value I expected (0 to 2).

Comment: *"It all works when I compile it in C, but in C++ it doesn't."* You compile something with `static_cast<>` in C? Didn't know that C supports that. And you cast form an `int32_t` to a `int32_t` so what is the point of that?

Comment: why do you cast to `int32_t*` ? The underlying type of an enum with 3 enumerators is not necessarily an `int32_t`. I dont know C, but in general it should not be a surprise that code that is valid C is not always valid C++. They are two different languages

Comment: The code you did post has too many things that are unclear (missing enum item, `static_cast` in code you say would be fine in C, missing `;` and maybe more). Nothing is really obvious, hence any little error you introduce in the code which is unrelated to your actual code makes it impossible for us to know what your actual code looks like. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: There is no guarantee that `sizeof(ITEMS_TYPE) == sizeof(int32_t)`. This means that casting a pointer to one of them to the other type and then dereferencing might not work as expected.

Comment: `int32_t valueToFind;` this is uninitialized, so Undefined Behavior.

Comment: int32_t valueToFind; is just an example, even if initialized it doesn't work. In my project that value comes from another function usually.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me in both C and C++. [C version](https://godbolt.org/z/4rzePG9dK), [C++ version](https://godbolt.org/z/GGvWo1P8P).

Comment: "int32_t valueToFind; is just an example," - there is no place for "is just an example, my code is different" in SO. If you show exactly the code causing the problem, then there is a chance someone can help. Otherwise it's just guessing around.

Comment: @pptaszni I've changed that, it is initialized now.

Comment: Can you show the real code that has the problem you're describing, as a [mre], instead of fake code, as you admitted is the code that you "changed"? The only thing that can possibly result from showing fake code on Stackoverflow is fake answers.

Comment: `index < arrayLastIndex` will break out of the for loop before it checks the last enum item. it should probably be `index <= arrayLastIndex` otherwise if the value you're looking for is `Item2` it wont be found. there are more issues in this code though, mostly stem from the fact you are writing C code in C++. you need to modify this for c++ and use something like a vector instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited the post, now it's exactly the same as I run on my PC.

Comment: @deviantgeek that's not the point. I'm not worried about the search mechanism now but about passing the pointer to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read attentively all the valuable comments above.

Here is a possible C++ way to go.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>

enum class ITEMS_TYPE { Item0, Item1, Item2 };

ITEMS_TYPE MyItemsArray[] = {ITEMS_TYPE::Item0, ITEMS_TYPE::Item1,
                             ITEMS_TYPE::Item2};

// computing fixed-size plain array size at compile-time
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t Size(T const (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}

bool findIndexOfItemInArray(ITEMS_TYPE valueToFind, ITEMS_TYPE* arrayToScan,
                            std::size_t arrayLastIndex,
                            std::size_t* indexOfTheSearchedValue) {
    std::size_t index;
    ITEMS_TYPE value;

    for (index = 0; index < arrayLastIndex; index++) {
        value = arrayToScan[index];
        if (value == valueToFind) {
            *indexOfTheSearchedValue = index;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(void) {
    ITEMS_TYPE valueToFind = ITEMS_TYPE::Item2;
    std::size_t itemIndex =
        static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    findIndexOfItemInArray(valueToFind, MyItemsArray, Size(MyItemsArray),
                           &itemIndex);
    return static_cast<int>(itemIndex);
}
```

First of all, I would avoid to rely on the actual numerical value of an `enum` item. It generally defeats the purpose of using an `enum` all-together.
Then I recommend the usage of scoped `enum` (`enum class`) which avoids name collision.
Use `std::size_t` for array index. In this code I added a possible function for automatically deducing the array size (`Size`).
Initialize properly variables. Here I give a special value to `index` (here, largest `int` value). It is not mandatory if you test your function output but, at least, you'll have a well defined value if the search fails.
Set severe compilation options and take care about all diagnosis returned by the compiler.
I hope it will help.
NB many other thing can be said about `enum` but I feel it is out of scope for your question.

[Live with "severe" compilation options](https://godbolt.org/z/T1zdjEY7h)

[EDIT] for the record an even more C++ version:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>

enum class ITEMS_TYPE { Item0, Item1, Item2 };

// ITEMS_TYPE MyItemsArray[] = {ITEMS_TYPE::Item0, ITEMS_TYPE::Item1,
//                              ITEMS_TYPE::Item2};

// C++14
std::array<ITEMS_TYPE, 3> MyItemsArray = {ITEMS_TYPE::Item0, ITEMS_TYPE::Item1,
                                          ITEMS_TYPE::Item2};

// C++17
// std::array MyItemsArray = {ITEMS_TYPE::Item0, ITEMS_TYPE::Item1,
//                            ITEMS_TYPE::Item2};

int main(void) {
    ITEMS_TYPE valueToFind = ITEMS_TYPE::Item2;
    std::size_t itemIndex =
        static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    auto first = std::cbegin(MyItemsArray);
    auto last = std::cend(MyItemsArray);
    auto res = std::find(first, last, valueToFind);

    if (res != last) {
        itemIndex = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::distance(first, res));
    }
    return static_cast<int>(itemIndex);
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/snGj6f3nT)

More modern C++ could be used also (`span` or `range`) but I'm not familiar enough with them.

[EDIT] critics on OP code
Above explanations are telling what should be done, not clearly why OP code was also wrong on low-level.
I wil repeat [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77066472/21691539), it cannot be assumed that the underlying type is `uint32_t`:
From [c++17 std draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) [dcl.enum]
10.2.7.

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can
> represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the
> enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. **It is implementation-defined** which integral type is used
> as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an
> enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as
> if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0

Thus the cast of then array of enums to `uint32_t *` is undefined behavior.
Instead, `reinterpret_cast<std::underlying_type_t<ITEMS_TYPE>*>(MyItemsArray)` could be used but, as said and explained at the beginning of this answer, I would consider such an usage as a bad practice.

Comment: you can pass pointer to first and one past the last element, or pass the array by reference, or a `std::span`, or use `std::array` to begin with. Imho anything is better than passing pointer to first element and size seperately.

Comment: of course there is better way to managed the array of values but it seemed out of scope to me (otherwise with may have gone for ```std::find```), don't you think so? IMHO, what was interesting for OP was what were the reasons behind its issue.

Comment: imho when the code is about finding element in an array then neither proper use of arrays nor `std::find` are "out of scope". Frankly, you mention lots of stuff, but what the actual issue in OPs code is, I dont know after reading this answer.

Comment: you miss to explain why the cast to `int32_t*` is wrong

Comment: 1. This is great, it works. 

2. Yes, I would like to see your way computing the arrayLastIndex automatically. My approach would be to add ItemLast to the enum class ITEMS_TYPE.

3. I use the enums as aliases for numbers because the project I work on is written partially in C and partially in C++. I'm not that good in C and terrible in C++.

4. The solution for my initial problem was to use size_t for indexing the array inside the findIndexOfItemInArray(). I would like to thank you especially for that suggestion.

Comment: My pleasure. I added the size deduction function (there perhaps exist a better way do to that but it does the job).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size in C++>=17. I'm soooooo C++14, sorry

Comment: @ 463035818_is_not_an_ai regarding the cast issue: indeed, it is addressed, I think, by [@pptaszni answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77066472].

Answer (score 3):

From [c++17 std draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) [dcl.enum]
10.2.7.

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can
> represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the
> enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. **It is implementation-defined** which integral type is used
> as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an
> enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as
> if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0

So you are causing undefined behaviour here by casting and dereferencing pointers to possibly different types, e.g. `std::int32_t` vs `std::uint32_t`. For example [gcc 13](https://godbolt.org/z/4xax891rT) is using unsigned integer as an underlying type of your enum.

Simply don't use enums where you need the integers (like a for loop). You can e.g. pass `std::vector<ITEMS_TYPE>` to your function, and do the lookup with `Item0` instead of literal integer 0.

Comment: "Simply don't use enums in the context where integers arithmetic is required. You can e.g. pass  [a vector of enums] ..." ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai like `for(int i = Item0; i < ItemEnd;` ... or whatever. I have seen many projects where someone started by defining enums for everything, and then end up with problems like that. How to iterate over enum. How to start iterating with some offset. How to exclude some enums from collection. Can I add/subtract two enums. All these problems wouldn't appear if they started with "what/why" instead of "how" == enum.

Comment: ok, thats how I understood the paragraph after pondering about it for while, I just think it is not very clear what you mean ;)